# Flat PCB connectors

Tags: pcb, connector

after finishing my prototype PCB I am now tasked to fit it inside a machine with almost no space. The PCB is not the problem but the Wire-to-board connectors.

After intensive search I was very overwhelmed of the selection. I narrowed it down to the JST-PH (horizontal 4.6mm) and the Molex DuraClik (6.4mm).

Do any of you know a flatter design, or an alternative?

Comment: Use flat cable ones. They can be down to 1.5mm tall

Comment: I did not think about flat ribbons. I will look into that

Comment: If you want to use wires, check the JST [SH connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=231), with a height of 2.9 mm. The [Molex PicoBlade system](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction) is closely following with 3.4 mm

Comment: Please note that questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are regarded off-topic as they are r̶a̶r̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶f̶u̶l̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶  quickly obsolete. (I definitely find this topic useful, but it will be(come) obsolete; my previous remark is from a research done 4 years ago and therefore outdated)

Comment: You can also consider FPC flex cable and a ZIF socket <1mm